# How do I add a custom PersistenceIOParticipant for webserver hosted .xamlx services using the web.config

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, sqlworkflowpersistencese

I'm trying to duplicate the functionality below using web.config since I'm using webserver hosted .xamlx services

```
host.WorkflowExtensions.Add(new HiringRequestInfoPersistenceParticipant());
```

I've tried the following from what I've been able to gather searching, but no satisfaction.

```
<extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="sqlTracking"
                 type="ApprovalService.Persistence.HiringRequestInfoPersistenceParticipant, ApprovalService.Persistence" />
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Here is my updated web.config

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="sqlTracking"
                 type="ApprovalService.HiringInfoElement, ApprovalService"/>
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <services>
        <service name="ApprovalService" behaviorConfiguration="ApprovalServiceBehavior">
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ApprovalServiceBehavior">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                <sqlWorkflowInstanceStore connectionStringName="WorkflowPersistence" />
                <workflowIdle timeToPersist="0" timeToUnload="0:05:0"/>
                <sqlTracking/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This all compiles and runs but the custom persistance object never get's called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add the sqlTracking behavior to your service behavior section?

The following is a working example

```
public class StringWriterElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get { return typeof(StringWriterBehavior); }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new StringWriterBehavior();
    }
}

public class StringWriterBehavior : IServiceBehavior
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, 
                                                                  ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        var host = (WorkflowServiceHost)serviceHostBase;
        host.WorkflowExtensions.Add<TextWriter>(() => new StringWriter());
    }
}
```

And the web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="stringWriter"
           type=" MyWorkflowService.StringWriterElement, MyWorkflowService"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
  <services>
    <service name="OrderWorkflow“
             behaviorConfiguration="OrderWorkflowBehavior">
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="OrderWorkflowBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        <stringWriter />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks Maurice, can you further explain a little bit?  My HiringRequestInfoPersistenceParticipant inherits from PersistenceIOParticipant.  Would I simply replace your stringWriter with my HiringRequestInfoPersistenceParticipant?  I guess WF figures out that it's a PersistenceParticipant and uses it appropriately?

Comment: I've added an updated config file, but my persistance object never get's called.  I can see the workflow itself get's persisted to the instance store in the InstancesTable but my custom persistence code never seems to get called.  I appreciate your continued help.

Comment: Can't really see anything wrong with the config. If you add a breakpoint to your ApplyDispatchBehavior() funtion. Do you actually get VS2010 to stop there?

Comment: no it was not hitting this, until I attached to the process (instead of stepping into).  Now it is hitting it and I'm able to discover the error is actually in my persistence participant.  I have to do a bit more troubleshooting on that but at least I know what is wrong now.  I would not have gotten it without your help on the original problem.  At least I'm configured now!