# How do you add extension into WF4 service workflow if activities are defined in seperate assembly?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

I have an assembly that defines some service interfaces (e.g. IAddressBookService).  I have referenced that assembly in an assembly of common WF activities.  When one of my common activities wants to use that service I want to get a reference for the service from the context extenstions e.g.

```
IAddressBookService myService = context.GetExtension<IAddressBookService>()
```

I want to use one of these common activities in a WorkFlow Service hosted by IIS.  However I can't figure out where I should add the concrete implmentation of IAddressBookService into the workflow context.  My concrete implmentations are not referenced by my assembly of common activites as I only want that library to reference the interfaces, so I can't use the "CacheMetadata" override, and I don't see any methods that are sure to be called on my workflow service activity in IIS before it starts up.  Also, as far I as can tell the WorkFlowExtenstionManager is not available when hosting the service on IIS.  Is there any common pattern for solving this or should I just create some sort of service locator to do this for me?

Thanks.

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is by defining a BehaviorExtensionElement and adding that to the web.config. See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558713/how-do-i-add-a-custom-persistenceioparticipant-for-webserver-hosted-xamlx-servi) question for an example.